# Problem with Constraint or Index SQL when Creating a Table

Tags: sql, indexing, constraints

I'm currently working on an assignment and have run into an issue.

I get an error:

> Msg 8135, Level 16, State 0, Line 41
>   Table level constraint or index does not specify column list, table 'Sessions'.

I've run through it a million times, but I cannot find out where the issue arises. I believe I AM specifying the columns in both table-level statements, so I am at a loss.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Class
(
    -- Column specifications and constraints--
    ClassID NCHAR(6) NOT NULL,  
    ClassDescription NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

    --Table constraints--
    CONSTRAINT pk_Class_ClassID 
        PRIMARY KEY (ClassID)   --ClassID is the primary key in the Class table, done as a table constraint
)

CREATE TABLE Riders
(
    -- Column specifications and constraints--
    RiderID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(10, 1)    --RiderID auto-fills in the value, starting at 10, incrementing by 1
        CONSTRAINT pk_Riders_RiderID PRIMARY KEY,   --RiderID is the primary key in the Riders table
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT chk_Riders_Name CHECK (LEN([Name]) > 4), --Name must be longer than 4 letters
    ClassID NCHAR(6) NULL,

    --Table constraints--
    CONSTRAINT fk_Riders_Class 
        FOREIGN KEY (ClassID) REFERENCES Class (ClassID)
)

CREATE TABLE [Sessions]
(
    -- Column specifications and constraints--
    RiderID INT NOT NULL,
    BikeID NCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    SessionDate DATETIME NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT chk_Sessions_SessionDate CHECK (SessionDate > '1 Sep 2017'), --SessionDate must be AFTER September 1, 2017
    Laps INT NULL,

    -- Table constraints--
    CONSTRAINT pk_Sessions_RiderID_BikeID_SessionDate 
        PRIMARY KEY (RiderID, BikeID, SessionDate), --RiderID, BikeID, SessionDate is the composite primary key for the Sessions table
    INDEX CI_Sessions_RiderID_BikeID ON [Sessions] (RiderID, BikeID)    --Index RiderID and BikeID
)

CREATE TABLE Bikes
(
    -- Column specifications and constraints--
    BikeID NCHAR(6) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT chk_Bikes_BikeID CHECK (BikeID LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][HYS]-[AP]') --BikeID in format ###X-A # = 0 - 9, X = H(Honda), Y(Yamaha), S(Suzuki), A = A(AM), P(PM)
        CONSTRAINT pk_Bikes_BikeID PRIMARY KEY, --BikeID is the primary key in the Bikes table
    StableDate DATE NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT def_Bikes_StableDate DEFAULT GETDATE()
)

ALTER TABLE [Sessions] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT chk_Sessions_Laps CHECK (Laps >= 10)

ALTER TABLE [Sessions] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Sessions_Riders 
        FOREIGN KEY (RiderID) REFERENCES Riders (RiderID)

ALTER TABLE [Sessions] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Sessions_Bikes 
        FOREIGN KEY (BikeID) REFERENCES Bikes (BikeID)
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `ON [Sessions]` from index definition and write as:

```
CREATE TABLE [Sessions]
(
    --Field specifications and constraints--
    RiderID int not null,
    BikeID nchar(6) not null,
    SessionDate datetime not null
        constraint chk_Sessions_SessionDate check (SessionDate > '1 Sep 2017'), --SessionDate must be AFTER September 1, 2017
    Laps int null,

    --Table constraints--
    constraint pk_Sessions_RiderID_BikeID_SessionDate primary key (RiderID, BikeID, SessionDate),   --RiderID, BikeID, SessionDate is the composite primary key for the Sessions table
    INDEX CI_Sessions_RiderID_BikeID (RiderID, BikeID)    --Index RiderID and BikeID
)
```

You can check which indexes are created using following script:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS table_name,
       name AS index_name, 
       type, type_desc
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Sessions', N'U');
```

[Demo here..](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e09fb5035f9e752ccb09cbb0796d0487)

Comment: This helped a lot!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

This error can occur if you use the keyword "Index" or "index" as a column name in your sql table. To fix this, use "indx" or something else.